# How to create a new folder & give permission in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight

I need to create a new sub folder say 'MyNewFolder' under My Documents.

I also need to grant permission my application or even everyone to read/write in 'MyNewFolder' folder.

I'm on OOB & elevated trust

How do I create a new folder & at the same time give permission to everyone to read/write on the new folder ?

Comment: OOB with Elevated Trust?

Comment: I guess he means the fact that you can set an OOB app to 'require elevated permissions'

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sub folder in My Documents with this code:-

```
   DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
   myDocs.CreateSubDirectory("MyNewFolder");
```

However you are not able to manipulate the folder's ACL hence you cannot make it available to everyone.

If you need to create a file which is available to everyone you will need to invoke the SaveFileDialog box and have the user specify a file location which has the appropriate security.